# SQLAlchemy Default DateTime, now plus n days from now

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I want to have a column with DateTime type which has a default value of 30 days from now

I cant set default now using `default=datetime.datetime.utcnow` but when I try to use something like `default=(datetime.datetime.utcnow + datetime.timedelta(days=30))`

It returns and error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.timedelta'`

A better example of my code:

```
class Example(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, default=(datetime.datetime.utcnow + datetime.timedelta(days=30)))
```

How can I do this without hardcoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create own function that will return the result:

```
def gen_valid_until():
    valid_until = date.today() + timedelta(days=7)
    return valid_until
```

And pass the function (not a result, so don't add ()) to default

```
class Share(db.Model):
    valid_until = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=gen_valid_until)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when `datetime.datetime.utcnow` is a function u can use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` as `datetime.datetime` class

> date = Column(DateTime, default=(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)))

Comment: We cant call the arguments, when we passing them

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the solution to this problem is not setting a default, or setting `datetime.datetime.utcnow` as default and then assign its default value on the class `__init__` method

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    date = Column(DateTime)

    def __init__(self, name, date=None):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date if date else datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

This is the only way that works

Dont ever use:

```
date = Column(DateTime, default=(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)))
```

You can't just pass a called argument as default, u have to pass the function itself, otherwise it will run the first time, and it will be replaced with its result on the first object you create, which means every object u create will have the same date as the first object..